# Alternative phrase to Mohammed must go to the mountain

Tags: phrase-requests

In the phrase: "If the mountain won't come to Mohammed then Mohammed must go to the mountain." I am looking for an alternative phrase for just the second part, "Mohammed must go to the mountain." A snappy phrase that implies that I need to go to them since they are unable to come to me. Any suggestions?

Comment: I can't see how you can change just the second part without making the whole thing a non-sequitur. E.g. "If the mountain won't come to Mohammed then steve must go to the clinic."

Comment: @KillingTime "If the mountain won't come to Mohammed, you can't make him drink. And it's worth 2 in the bush." :)

Comment: What's wrong with "Mohammed must go to the mountain"? We could give you a phrase that is only trivially different (such as "Mohammed must walk to the mountain"), but presumably, there's something that you don't like about the original phrase, and so presumably you're looking for a phrase that doesn't have that undesirable quality.

Comment: “I do house calls”?

Comment: @Steve Please follow our [detailed help for phrase requests](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/phrase-requests/info).

Comment: This is for the title of a small photographic club newsletter article. I have been commissoned to go and take some photos of a sports club, I couldn't get them to come to me so had the idea of calling the article "Taking Mohammed To The Mountain" but it is a multi racial club and it has been suggested I avoid the Mohammed reference so I need to find an alternative the conjours up the same idea.

Comment: @SteveShute Please follow the guidance  I've linked to and make sure all relevant information is included in the question. You can edit the question.

Comment: An answer to "https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/561111/english-equivalent-of-the-greek-when-muhammad-does-not-go-to-the-mountain" suggests "If you can't come to the party, we'll bring the party to you". If this is not quite what you want, you might try reversing it.

Comment: You can change the whole metaphor: 'Sometimes, a house visit is necessary.' Though this isn't an idiom.